# Splitting Google Form response (type = long answer) by line break and merging them with html break

Tags: google-sheets

I have a long answer type question in my Google Form the responses of which are uploaded on the website via CSV. The response comes like this:
[image: response]

How can I add `<br>` in between of every line?
Can we achieve both splitting and combining in one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working usign this piece of formula:
`=textjoin("<br>",true,(transpose(split(join(char(10),A1:A4),char(10)))))`

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` has 50000 character limitation so:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, CHAR(10), "<br>"), "<br><br>", "<br>")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A, CHAR(10), "<br>"), 
 "<br><br>", "<br>")&"<br>",,999^99), "<br> <br.*$", ""))
```

[image: 0]